# SVG scaling for % with parent container

Tags: javascript, css, svg, scale

I want to have an inline svg element's contents scale when size is non-native. CSS scale and viewBox have px scale. But my need percent scale. How realize it? Without css background-size.

```
<style>div,a{width:100%}div{background:green}svg{transform:scale(25%,25%)</style>

<div><a>
<svg><circle cx="90" cy="59" r="59" fill="red"/><path d="M53,49H127V69H53z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
</a></div>
```

Comment: Edit the file/code and change to percent scale.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I add my code. Its not work :(. transform:scale and viewBox have px scale, but my need percent scale. CSS background:(url) its no good, its 1 request.